# When inverting Vector3 value compiler complains about Syntax

Tags: c#, vector, syntax-error, expected-exception

Today im struggling with vectors, and im having problems with this. I have to invert the Y vector value but everytime i compile , Compiler complains about:

> Syntax error ',' expected

```
 vector = new Vector3((float) ((-256 + ((iD & 7) * 0x40)) + 0x20), (float) ((-512 + ((iD / 8) * 0x40)) + 0x20), -200f) {
   Y = -vector.Y;  //error shows here at the semicolon
 };
```

Comment: What is your `Y` variable declared as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using object initializer syntax.

The compiler is correct.

You would place a comma there, instead of the semicolon, if you were to initialize more than one property. The comma is also legal even after the last property being initialized, but a semicolon is not legal.

So either of the following two is OK:

```
vector = new Vector3((float) ((-256 + ((iD & 7) * 0x40)) + 0x20), (float) ((-512 + ((iD / 8) * 0x40)) + 0x20), -200f) {
   Y = vector.Y
 }; 

vector = new Vector3((float) ((-256 + ((iD & 7) * 0x40)) + 0x20), (float) ((-512 + ((iD / 8) * 0x40)) + 0x20), -200f) {
   Y = vector.Y,
 };
```

Having said that, this will only satisfy the compiler. *What are you really trying to do*?

Please note that at the point where you read `vector.Y`, the `vector` variable has not yet been given a new value, so you're reading the old value.

Basically, the code is doing this:

```
var temp = = new Vector3((float) ((-256 + ((iD & 7) * 0x40)) + 0x20), (float) ((-512 + ((iD / 8) * 0x40)) + 0x20), -200f);
temp.Y = vector.Y;
vector = temp;
```

Why aren't you simply assigning that through the constructor instead?

```
vector = new Vector3((float) ((-256 + ((iD & 7) * 0x40)) + 0x20), vector.Y, -200f);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could place a comma after the last property in an initializer.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: It was allowed in order to make it easier for generated code to avoid having to deal with *not* placing a comma after the last value. It's legal in array and collection initializers as well.

Comment: Thanks about that, ive not noticed that. Also i have other question. Do i have to ask in a new question?